# Is there a javadoc library for all current extlib packages?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

Yesterday a customer asked me whether there is some kind of javadoc library available for all the extlib control objects, like we have it for the standard Xpage related controls: 
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/index.html

All I could say was "have a look at XpagesExt.nsf and see how *they* did it...". Which is quite a lame answer, I feel. So I spent half this morning googling but couldn't find anything. Anyone having a link for me?

Thanks,
Lothar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've added it to the [OpenNTF XPages Knowledge Base](https://wiki.openntf.org/display/GEN/XPages+Components+and+Complex+Types+XML+Schema+and+JavaDoc+Documentation), in the General space, but also cross-linked from the Extension Library space. You can find the XML definitions for components and complex types as well as the JavaDoc for Extension Library. I will endeavour to keep it up to date as releases come out (it's not onerous, so should not be an issue).

I will take forward an action for the next OpenNTF board meeting to see if we can host Javadocs for this online on the OpenNTF site somewhere (as well as other OpenNTF projects). It looks like there's not a way to host them [within Confluence](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/177809/generate-javadoc-and-publish-on-confluence) (the product used for the Knowledge Base), but that should not be a barrier. We may also be able to add Extension Library into the build process to automate the generation and publishing.